# Pygame false sprite collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I've got a Group of sprites and I'm trying to test for collisions. However, I seem to get a lot of collisions instantly between my player sprite and my enemy sprites.

I have tried:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, True)
print "hits is this long: " + str(len(hits))
for i in hits:
    player.damage()
```

but this just immediately kills off all my enemies. I included the

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

on the objects.

Then I have tried:

```
for o in enemy_list:
    o.draw()
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, o)==True:
        print "careful " + str(player.health)
        player.damage()
```

but still again, nothing.

What is the easiest way of detecting the collision between enemy and player? 
TIA

My whole code is visible at: 
https://github.com/kabads/zoomr/blob/master/zoomr.py

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `pygame` runs your main loop hundreds of times a second. Therefore, what you might think of as a simple collision and then pass over, the interpreter will interpret each time that your player is passing over an enemy as a hit and so it will run so quickly, your enemy/player will die almost instantly. To avoid this problem, you should make the two bounce off each other so that only one collision happens at a time. This can be done by flipping the `dx` or `dy` values (if you have any).

I suggest you check this out: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation/boundaries

See how he moves the ball sprite back into the box, if it exceeds the boundaries, AND reverses the direction of travel.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure what you mean - my sprites aren't moving when the game begins.

Comment: @Adam, Oh I see what you mean. Please wait a few minutes.

Comment: Ah, thinking about it- these sprites aren't images - they are just drawn squares - does that mean that the image.get_rect won't return anything?

Comment: @Adam, Possibly. Try using images instead.

Comment: OK - switched to images (blue.jpg and red.jpg) and still getting the same results - i.e. false collision.